# Need to create route to bypass VPN which allocate full traffic as default route

Tags: vpn, route, iproute2

I have 2 VPNs: utun0 and ppp0.

```sh
ip r s
default via 175.15.105.123 dev utun0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev en0
127.0.0.0/8 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo0
169.254.0.0/16 dev en0  scope link
10.0.15.0/24 via ppp0 dev ppp0
```

When i connect to utun0 then ppp0 stop working due to
its allocates full network connections to its own.

But i want that ppp0 services will be still available, i.e 10.0.15.0/24

When i try create route with

```sh
ip route add 10.0.15.0/24 via 10.0.15.100 dev en0
```

it doesn’t help and all requests still not works

**Update**

```sh
ip l s
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1300
    ether 60:f8:1d:b1:f8:5c 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:f8:1d:b1:f8:5c 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether ea:3a:29:c1:d5:a3 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:07:7c:d8:b0 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:07:7c:d8:b1 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:07:7c:d8:b0 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 8 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1200
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

```sh
 ip a s
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 lo0
    inet6 ::1/128
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scopeid 0x1
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1300
    ether 60:f8:1d:b1:f8:5c
    inet6 fe80::60:f174:65a8:ec30/64 secured scopeid 0x5
    inet 192.168.0.141/24 brd 192.168.0.255 en0
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether ea:3a:29:c1:d5:a3
    inet6 fe80::e83a:29ff:fec1:d5a3/64 scopeid 0x7
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1080
    inet 10.0.15.100 --> 10.0.15.0/24 ppp0
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1200
    inet 175.15.105.123 --> 175.15.105.123/32 utun0
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! Can you please [edit] your question and post the output of `ip address show` and `ip link show`?

Comment: Hello! It should be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by myself.

sudo route add -net 192.168.0.141/24 gw  en0

it works now.